# How to connect to Wi-Fi in a browser

Tags: javascript, browser, wifi

I have been searching for an answer on how to connect to a WiFi hotspot using Javascript in browser.

Context: I'm building a page that show WiFi information such as SSID and Password after scanning a QRCode, and the page shows which Network you're going to connect to before actually connecting for security

I have found this : [php-wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55276422), which seems to be what I want in PHP, but nothing for Wifi interface in Browser Javascript, I've search "wifi" in npmjs but no success.

I'd like it to work on all devices, if possible

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be impossible to scan network on browser due to restricted access by design, but you could do it on Node.JS with this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wifi.

For browser, only limited network information could be retrieved, check this document: https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was reading it here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API
Maybe I should explore how to open a QRCode encoded string to do so https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#wi-fi-network-config-android-ios-11 ?

Comment: If it doesn't work in browser JS, how the PHP one works ? Maybe I could try to mimic it ?

Comment: PHP is a server-side language, like Node.JS, the data you retrieved by using those library is from the server not from the browser client. Therefore, if your client could install PHP and Node.JS, then browser could act like a frontend and connect to the server for manipulating the network interface, but that's not in the case, as you want to achieve is the client uses JavaScript via browser provided API without any additional installation to manipulate the network interface.